# How to send POST request from React front to PHP backend?

Tags: php, reactjs

I would send POST request from react frontend to php backend.
Here is code.

--frontend

```
fetch(backendUrl + "/list", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(filterData)
})
.then(function(res) {
    return res.json()
})
.then(function(data) {
    self.setState({
        OddList: data.list
    });
    self.props.setPageCount(data.page_count);
    self.props.onShowLoading(false);
})
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What error are you getting?

Comment: I want to send POST request. but it sends OPTIONS request. Then nothing happen

Comment: Is your React app on the same domain as your PHP backend?

Comment: No it is different domain.

Comment: don't play with fetch,Use `axios` or some other library

Comment: Thanks I will try.

Comment: You need to investigate CORS, as your request is cross origin, and that explains the `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: This is PHP backend part. 

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == "OPTIONS")
        {
            echo "OK";
            return;
        }

Comment: can you post the value you are getting as "backendUrl" ?

Comment: Can you post the network tab in developer options expanding the request your are sending ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It 's mentioned in the comments that you have a different domain for the PHP API you are using. I think the problem is there.

If you use this way the request will go to something similar to bellow URL

ex

```
http://frontendappdomain/backendurl/list
```

While you actually want to hit  something similar to bellow URL

```
http://phpappdomaint/backendurl/list
```

Try sending the full URL instead of the "pathname". That would solve your problem if I understood your problem correctly.